# Can't find lpython2.7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, gcc, cygwin

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lpython2.7
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I am working on `cygwin`, trying to install `sentry` and encountered this error?

Can anyone tell why I am running into this problem, is the problem related to `python-dev` package ?

Also how to install python-dev on cygwin if required ?

Comment: Do you have `python2.7-dev` installed?

Comment: @Wintro that's the problem, I tried to run pip install python-dev in cygwin but it return the error, Moreover while installing cygwin I tried to add relevant file to install, but I don't have a sure shot way of knowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search a package containing a file you can use `cygcheck` or https://cygwin.com/packages/

Using cygcheck in your case:

```
$ cygcheck -p libpython2.7.dll.a
Found 3 matches for libpython2.7.dll.a
python-devel-2.7.12-1 - python-devel: Python language interpreter (installed binaries and support files)
python-2.7.10-1 - python: Python language interpreter (installed binaries and support files)
python2-devel-2.7.13-1 - python2-devel: Python 2 language interpreter
```

So you need to install with `Cygwin Setup` the `python2-devel` package
as it is the last version with the right file.
Do not use `pip install` for packages already available from `Cygwin Setup`

Comment: This is indeed the right answer. I found the offending file by searching for the lib file with: `find /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/ -iname "libpython*"`. Then I did the `cygcheck` above which showed it didn't belong to any package. Then used `apt-cyg python2-devel` fixed everything. (Google for the highly useful `apt-cyg` tool.)